# Tetris background sound

Tags: tetris

I am making a tetris game using glut libraries.I want to have sound in background.

I have this code.Will it work?

```
BOOL sndPlaySound(
  LPCTSTR lpszSound,  
  UINT fuSound       
);
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

`sndPlaySound` is deprecated, and you should use `PlaySound` from winmm.{lib|dll}

For example:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("tetris.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

The last parameter is flags: `SND_FILENAME` says the first parameter should be interpreted as a file to be loaded. `SND_ASYNC` says that the function should return immediately, not wait for the sound to finish before returning the control.

Note that this is all winMM library (`#include "windows.h"`), and has nothing to do with GLUT.

Comment: I am working in ubuntu.Do it works for ubuntu as well

Comment: @sadia Of course. Both are Windows only. You copied the declaration from a Microsoft site! I don't know what's a good choice for Ubuntu, perhaps OpenAL http://www.openal-soft.org/ (plays well with openGL), or PortAudio http://www.portaudio.com/